# Can't find file specified?

Tags: java, file, java-io

Am I losing my mind? My BufferedReader cannot find the file specified, but I am absolutely sure I have the correct path (I have checked numerous times, stepped through...I have no idea what is going on).

Here is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;


/**
* Code for E11.8. Searches all files specified on the command line and 
prints out all lines     
containing a specified word.
* @author - Matthew Arnold
*/
public class Find {
/**
  Searches file for a word, prints out all lines containing that word.
  @param wordToFind the word to find
  @param filename the filename for the file to search
*/
public static void findAndPrint(String wordToFind, String fileName)throws IOException{

   BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));

   ArrayList<String> stringsFromFile = new ArrayList<>();

   while(br.ready()) {
       stringsFromFile.add(br.readLine());
   }

   for(String s : stringsFromFile) {
       if(s.contains(wordToFind))
           System.out.println(s);
   }

   br.close();
}

 /**
  First argument of the main method should be the word to be searched
  For other arguments of the main method, store the file names to be examined
*/
public static void main(String[] args)
{
   String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + "\\Desktop\\mary.txt";
  System.out.println(fileName);


  try {
        findAndPrint("lamb", fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

Perhaps another set of eyes can see what I am not. Any help is greatly appreciated. Thank you.

EDIT- **Added in recommended test lines & included stacktrace:**

Updated code (in main):

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
 {
   String fileName = System.getProperty("user.home") + 
 "\\Desktop\\mary.txt";
  System.out.println(fileName);


  try {
        System.out.println(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());
        findAndPrint("lamb", fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

 }
}
```

Output:

```
C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\mary.txt
C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\mary.txt
java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\mary.txt (The 
system cannot find the file specified)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
at java.io.FileInputStream.open(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(Unknown Source)
at java.io.FileReader.<init>(Unknown Source)
at Find.findAndPrint(Find.java:21)
at Find.main(Find.java:50)
```

Comment: Run this: `System.out.println(new File(fileName).getAbsolutePath());` and check the file is *really* where you think it is.

Comment: "_I am absolutely sure I have the correct path_" Show us what path is being used in that method.

Comment: print the `filename`

Comment: @csmckelvey I do, unless I'm misunderstanding. String fileName in the main method

Comment: It will be great if you could add the stacktrace.

Comment: That is the variable name - I am asking about what the value is. What path is actually being used? You will have to print it to the console or check it in the debugger and then provide it here.

Comment: Usually the problem is an incorrect belief of what the current directory is.

Comment: @csmckelvey C:\Users\Matthew\Desktop\mary.txt

Comment: Well I updated the code to include necessary additions.

Comment: This may be a long shot, but are you POSITIVE the file is called `mary.txt`? On Windows machines, the file extension is often hidden by default. The real filename might actually be `mary.txt.txt` even though you only see `mary.txt` when looking on your desktop.

Comment: @Zephyr lmao bro- that was it. haha. Thanks for the help :)

Comment: @Matthew - haha easy mistake :) Glad we got it sorted out!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the trouble could be in the path separator you could use File.separator and do something like that :

```
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
     String fileName = String.join(File.separator,System.getProperty("user.home"),"Desktop","mary.txt");
    System.out.println(fileName);

    try {
        findAndPrint("lamb", fileName);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```